# Import Leaflet Markers from a external GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet

I am starting with leaflet and wanted to display more information when clicking on a marker in a map using a sidebar.

I use the php call where the geoJeson called allande_geoJson is generated with all the information I need from my database:

In the example I'm using, a maker is generated so that when you click on it, the information is displayed in the sidebar:

```
var marker = L.marker([51.2, 7]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
            sidebar.toggle();
        });
```

[image]

I wanted to enter the makers directly from my geoJeson and I am trying various ways with no success, such as:

```
var marker= L.marker(new L.GeoJSON(allande_geoJson)).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
            sidebar.toggle();
        });
```

any ideas?

Comment: Pls create a working example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

The Markers are loaded automatically when you put the geojson data in the `L.geoJSON()` layer.

With `onEachFeature` you add the click event to each marker.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function () {
            sidebar.toggle();
        });
}

L.geoJSON(allande_geoJson, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: when I write the code I have the following answer: Uncaught TypeError: L.geoJSON is not a function

Comment: @busto Pls try if the following works: `L.marker()`, `new L.GeoJSON()`, `L.geoJSON()`

Comment: the code is correct, I have realized that the error was due to not having updated the version of leaflet. thanks everyone!